# How to close appbar (Windows 8 Metro)

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, windows-runtime, appbar

When I tap on icon in bottom appbar it stays open. I need close it when button clicked. How can I achieve this?

I'm using C#, XAML.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Set IsOpen=false. That should be enough.

Comment: Thank you. For some reason I expected that IsOpen is readonly. I usually use prefix "is" for readonly state properties. I excepted something like method .Show() or property .Visible.